# Selecting text without an ID or class using jQuery selectors

Tags: jquery, dom, jquery-selectors

With the following template how can I get just get "Obtain this text"

```
<h1 class="classA classB">
        Obtain this text 
        <span class="unwanted">
            unwanted text
        </span>
</h1>
```

I tried `$('.classA.classB:not(.unwanted)')` but I get the whole thing back without unwanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#foo")
    .clone()    //clone the element
    .children() //select all the children
    .remove()   //remove all the children
    .end()  //again go back to selected element
    .text();    //get the text of element
```

.remove() accepts a selector , so you can do something like `.remove('.unwanted')`

sourse 
http://viralpatel.net/blogs/jquery-get-text-element-without-child-element/

demo

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/demo/jquery/get-text-without-child-element/

please google before asking

Answer (score 2):

[***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/ZvtDZ/) 
Clone it, drop the kids, get the text:

```
$('.classA').clone().find('.unwanted').remove().end().text();
```